# Exception org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: ..element not visible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to select radio button but getting "ElementNotVisibleException:" exception.please refer below code

```
public class Automatecheckbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

       WebElement male_radio_button=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_c']"));


       boolean status=male_radio_button.isDisplayed();

       System.out.println("Male radio button is Displayed >>"+status);

        boolean enabled_status=male_radio_button.isEnabled();

        System.out.println("Male radio button is Enabled >>"+enabled_status);

      boolean selected_status=male_radio_button.isSelected();

        System.out.println("Male radio button is Selected >>"+selected_status);

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        male_radio_button.click();

      boolean selected_status_new=male_radio_button.isSelected();

        System.out.println("Male radio button is Selected >>"+selected_status_new);

    }

}
```

Comment: At which line are you seeing `ElementNotVisibleException` ? Can you update the Question with the entire error stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find element using this code :

```
WebElement male_radio_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='u_0_c']"));
```

Hope it will work!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the explicit wait (WebDriverWait) to let the WebElement get loaded before performing any execution on it. WebDriverWait object (in this case `wait`) is initialized just after invoking the `ChromeDriver();`

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

/* Initialize the WebDriverWait, with 30 seconds of wait time. */
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_c']")));
WebElement male_radio_button=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_c']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='2']")).click();
```